# EXCEL UI Custom Ribbon: Two add-in for only one Custom Tab

Tags: excel, custom-controls, ribbon

I've got two add-in that need to create a group of buttons in a custom tab.
I'm trying to use the same Custom tab for the 2 add-ins, and so to create the two groups in this custom tab.

I've tried to set the same namespace, the same tab Id, but whatever, each time two custom tab are created, with in each one the group created by each add-in...

Is there a way to get that work?

Here is an example for the custom UI xml for the first add-in :

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="MYCOMPANYRibbonOnLoad" xmlns:x="MYCOMPANYSpace">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab id="MYCOMPANYTab" label="MYCOMPANY" insertAfterMso="TabView">
<group id="IDGroup1" label="LabelGroup1">
<button id="Group1customButton1" (etc...)/>
<button id="Group1customButton2" (etc...)/>
<button id="Group1customButton3" (etc...) />
<button id="Group1customButton4" (etc...) />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

And Here is an example for the custom UI xml for the second add-in :

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="MYCOMPANYRibbonOnLoad" xmlns:x="MYCOMPANYSpace">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab id="MYCOMPANYTab" label="MYCOMPANY" insertAfterMso="TabView">
<group id="IDGroup2" label="LabelGroup2">
<button id="Group2customButton1" (etc...) />
<button id="Group2customButton2" (etc...) />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Me too! Same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the solution :

First you have to declare your own namespace like this:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" xmlns:n="http://ISBN3-86063-989-7.com/RibbonXML" onLoad="RibbonOnLoad">
```

Then you need to use the idQ attribute in conjunction with your namespace alias (and not only Id attribute as I did first):

```
<tab idQ="n:YourCustomTab_Id" label="YourCustomTab_Name" insertAfterMso="TabView">
```

If you want to separate with group, you need to declare groups in the same way:

```
<group idQ="n:YourCustomGroup1_Id" label="YourCustomGroup1_Name">
```

It worked well in my case...

Comment: This link has more information on how to do this.   https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/sharing-custom-tabs-in-the-ribbon-ui/
Thanks for finding the answer to this question, it was exactly what I was looking to do as well.

Comment: Glad it could help, as I spent some times searching the solution...
By the way, be carefull with the 'idQ', specifically if you use it for groups. Don't know if it's normal behaviour or a bug but when you use idQ for groups, 'GetVisible' state linked to a function doesn't work at all, the function will never be called...So I had to use only 'id' for my groups...no pb until you need to merge some controls of two add-in into the same group...